# Riemann-integrable iff pointwise limit of step functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, riemann-sum

Is the following true? Let $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ be a bounded function:

> The function $f$ is Riemann-integrable if and only if there exists a sequence of step functions $\varphi_n$ converging pointwise to $f$.

Comment: It is not true. Look at the indicator function of the Smith-Volterra-Cantor set. (see e.g. on Wikipedia) It can be approximated by step functions but is not Riemann-integral since the lower sums do not converge to the Lebesgue measure of the set (i. e. the Lebesgue integral of the indicator function)

Comment: Ok, thank you. And does the other implication hold, i.e. if $f$ is Riemann-integrable, does there exists a sequence of step functions converging pointwise to $f$?

Comment: Depending on how general your step functions are (*viz*, what sets you allow for the indicator functions), ANY bounded function is a pointwise limit of step functions.

Comment: The proofs I know use *simple* function, i.e. finite linear combinatios of arbitrary sets, but step functions are finite linear combinations of *intervals*, so are you sure that every bounded function is the pointwise limit of step functions?

Answer (score 0):

One of my students asked the same question, so I decided to post an answer here in case it helps.

Both sides are not correct. We now construct a Riemann integrable function which cannot be approximated pointwise by step functions.

1. Let $D$ be a non-Borel measurable subset of the Cantor set $C$, and let $f=1_D$ the indicator function of $D$.
   Then $f$ is Riemann integrable but not Borel measurable.
   The Riemann integrability of  $f$ can either be proved by definition, or by the Riemann-Lebesgue theorem. In fact,
   since $f$ agrees with the indicator function $1_C$ on the open set $\mathbb{R}\setminus C$,  we can deduce from the continuity of $1_C$ on $\mathbb{R}\setminus C$ that  $f$ is continuous on  $\mathbb{R}\setminus C$. Hence $f$ is a bounded function whose discontinuity has measure zero.
2. Also note that any step function is Borel measurable, and a pointwise limit of Borel measurable functions is Borel measurable. So $f$ can not be a pointwise limit of step functions.